# How to bind Master and sub report dynamically in c# (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have done crystal report with master and sub report through ODBC connection(Directly connecting to database using SQL query). Report has around 400 pages and takes 15 mins local but when I have deployed in server it was taking hour to complete. How to increase performance here ?

I am following different approach to overcome above issue using ADO.NET data source(Stored procedure with programmatic) using typed data set. 
Here for master report I have bound data source from Stored procedure but how can I bind for sub report pragmatically ?

Each sub report need parameter from master report. I have one master and sub report, both reports needs to bind based on data.
Please help me out to bind master and sub report using C# code using Stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say for sure but if you've already got a stored procedure for the main report you're probably best off incorporating the data/functionality of the sub report into that same stored proc. Calling a sub report for each row in a big report was probably the slow part of your report in the first place, it's generally inefficient.